# SIP returns are negative due to COVID-19

Tags: india, mutual-funds, covid-19

Today, I checked all of my SIP accounts.  I was shocked to see that the absolute returns for all of the schemes that I have been doing for the past 5 years are negative. It is because of COVID-19.

Should I need to worry at this point of time?

What advice would you suggest?

Comment: What country are you in? Do you have broad funds in your portfolio or individual equities?

Comment: All are equities (Large cap and mid cap) - country - India

Comment: What age are you in?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to make a few assumptions, the big one being that you are relatively young with many years until retirement and that this is your first major market correction.  If so then there is one historical truth: the markets have trended up over the long run. There are periods when it goes down but over many, many years, the overall return is positive.

Re "What advice would you suggest?", do not panic.  Allow the overall trend to reassert itself. Many years from now, you might not even notice this blip.

Focus on your long-term goals.  Slow and steady investing in diversified assets has worked for a very, very long time.